# 16.04 updates after new installation

Tags: updates

Muon offers over 400 updates! They all all pre-selected. How can I remove
selections and just mark some that I want? (I'm just starting Kubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

It is always better to keep your system up-to-date. If you didn't add any ppa's, all updates you have recived are necessary. You can do this in terminal:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

It is absolutely normal, that you will get some updates 4-5 times in week.